# General questions about setting up a database for my app

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

In my app I have a table. I want to populate the data in this table by executing SQL queries that will pull the data from a database. I have some resources on setting up a database but they don't answer my more general questions:

1. Are all databases live i.e. once someone downloads my app from the app store, is the app interacting with a live database that I can still update from my end?
2. Is it possible for me to insert data into my database from an Excel file? If so, can you point to any resources that will help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Once the user downloads your application and runs it, a new SQLite database is created locally on the user's device for the application which is only available locally to the user and not you hence, you cannot have access to the database. If you want something like that, check out [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) i.e. Cloud Storage.

2) **Ideally**, you should only access the database from the application that uses the database to store data but you can check this [link](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/connecting-excel-sqlite-42473.html) on how to work with Excel.

Just as an addition, check out [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) which provides an abstraction layer over SQLite to allow fluent database access while harnessing the full power of SQLite.